# filter datagrid using datetimepicker in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to filter `datagrid` by choosing a date from `datetimepicker`. I did this in another form and it works fine. But in an another form same code doesn't work. Here is the code. Thanks for advance.

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("CONVERT(" + dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName + ", System.String) like '%"
        + dateTimePicker1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: It is not clear why you need the LIKE operator to filter on a DateTime value.

Comment: i used LIKE because it was worked before in same scenario.

Comment: If you look at the examples in the [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN you will see that filtering on a Date column is done using a syntax like this _ColumName = #1/19/2016#_ or _ColumName = '1/19/2016'_  depending on the provider. You could try that and tell us if it works

Comment: well... it did not work Steve. anyway thanks for your concern

Comment: i used my code to search in datagrid as the datetimepicker's value is.

Comment: A DateTimePicker is used to get a DateTime value using the property Value. Then you are trying to convert it to a string and in this process the output string represents your date according to a format choosen by the the CONVERT function. Then you check against the values in the grid column. If this column contains a DateTime value then your check probably fails. If the column contains strings then the check works sometime depending how the CONVERT function works. It is better to fill the column with DateTime values and then check agains a DateTime value

Comment: you are absolutely right Steve. can you send me code pls.